# How many $4$ digits numbers can be obtained by using $1,1,2,3,4,5$?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, factorial, combinatorics-on-words

My friend asked me this question. First I am wondering whether this problem is well defined.
However, my attemp was:

a. Counting all 4 digits numbers from $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ which is $5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2= 120$ options. I meant that no double $1$ will appear.

b. $4$ digits numbers with double $1$: there are $4$ ways to locate  $8$ twice. multiplying by $4 \cdot 3=12$ options to fill in the last two digits we get: $48$ options.

So eventually there are $168$ numbers that satisfy these conditions.

Am I correct? should it be written more rigorously?

Comment: Part (a) is good.  In part (b), there are $\binom{4}{2} = 6$ ways of locating the two $1$'s.  Once these are located, then there are two remaining slots that can be filled in $(4 \times 3)$ different ways.  Therefore, Part (b) should be $(6 \times 12 = 72).$

Comment: First thank you. I understand the calculation, just can't see practically more than 4 ways $$
\begin{aligned}
&11-- \\
&1--1 \\
&1-1- \\
&--11
\end{aligned}
$$  . What other 2 options to locate ones left?

Comment: 11--, 1-1-, 1--1, -11-, -1-1, --11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the complement of your second and third cases. $-11-$ and $-1-1$

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).